# Can not start Cassandra 2.0 on Ubuntu 13.04 "upgrade to 1.2.5+ first"

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I tried to install Cassandra 2.0 on my Ubuntu 13.04, but I'm getting this error when i try to start it:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Commitlog segment is too old to open; upgrade to 1.2.5+ first
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogDescriptor.fromFileName(CommitLogDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment$CommitLogSegmentFileComparator.compare(CommitLogSegment.java:391)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment$CommitLogSegmentFileComparator.compare(CommitLogSegment.java:386)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:324)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:189)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:124)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:300)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:443)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:486)
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you upgrading from an older version of Cassandra?  If so, you should upgrade to 1.2.9 first.  Then upgrade to 2.0.0.  Some of the datafiles are not forward compatible.

Comment: After little digging, i found a solution.

As Aurand asked me, yes, I was upgrading from another version, and this was the root cause of my problem.

I didn't tried upgrade first to 1.2.9, because it was my development machine. I just removed Cassandra and deleted my /var/lib/cassandra.

After this I reinstalled and everthing worked fine.

I beleive that what Aurand told me to do, should work also.

Thanks for your help @Aurand.

Comment: Maybe you could accept his solution then.

Comment: I ran into this problem. FGRibreau's solution didn't help (it ran, but I still ran into the error). So I just wiped and recreated the /var directories that were related to cassandra. All set. IMPORTANT: This assumes that there is no data in your system!

Answer (score 4):

I'll expand a little on what @aurand is saying, here is **how to upgrade Cassandra from 0.x or 1.1.x to 2.x**.

First upgrade to **1.2.9** `apt-get install cassandra=1.2.9`.

Then run `nodetool upgradesstables` (you have to otherwise some unexpected things will happen) , follow this process with `nodetool compactionstats` (or even better `watch -n 2 nodetool compactionstats`) it may take **days** depending on your data.

Finally upgrade to the latest version `apt-get install cassandra` and run `nodetool upgradesstables` again.
Then you're done.

Note: instead of `nodetool upgradesstables` you may use `nodetool scrub` but it seems to be recommended to **[use `upgradesstables` instead](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/nodetool#nodetool-scrub)**.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the exact same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 and I was able to solve it by removing /var/lib/cassandra completely, as user2278196 suggested in the comments of his original question.

Mind you: I did this on a reasonably clean system, so I was completely sure I wouldn't loose any information.

I don't think you could do this on a machine that has actual data without losing it. Be careful!